# How to reduce the memory usage of a C# console application project?

Tags: c#, memory

This is program consumes 36.50 MB of memory but I want it to be less than 32 MB

```
public static void CreateText(string text)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(text.Length) <= 80)
    {
        int n;
        string str = "";
        string count = "";
        char[] mas = text.ToCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(mas.Length); i++)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(mas[i].ToString(), out n))
            {
                count += mas[i].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(count))
                {
                    str += mas[i].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < Convert.ToInt32(count); j++)
                    {
                        str += mas[i].ToString();
                    }
                    count = "";
                }
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: why this `Convert.ToInt32(text.Length)`? `text.Length`  is already INT Type

Comment: I'd say using `Convert.ToInt32` like that is an anti-pattern; it's even hiding a potential bug in the nested for loop.

Comment: this is not enough memory

Comment: Maybe a stringbuilder can save you

Comment: What does your input look like?

Comment: @Mast Then why would this tag exist? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memory-optimization
I see questions all the time asking for code review guidance on a particular area. The help page says questions on performance are allowed for working pieces of code. Memory would be considered performance would it not?

Not trying to argue or anything, I just see questions like this all the time on code review, so I thought it might be helpful to post it there.

Comment: This seems... arbitrary. What is your exact goal here?

Comment: Just open profiler and look at which object has been created frequently and consumed lot of memory.

Comment: @Shelby115 I'd expect that tag on a question also tagged with 'embedded' in a language lower than C#.

Comment: Also... I'm not sure that `count += mas[i].ToString();` line does what you think it does.

Comment: @Shelby115 Whilst questions on Code Review are encouraged to mention any particular *preferences* they have for improving their code, CR is for **general** code improvements for **any and every** aspect of a piece of code. **Specific** programming questions are literally **the** definition of On-Topic for Stack Overflow (To quote the On-Topic section of the Help Center: "a specific programming problem")

Answer (score 1):

To reduce memory footprint you need to get read of temporary string objects generated by applying operation `+=` against a string. String is immutable object in C#, so `+=` creates new string. StringBuilder is mutable, so use it instead of string. You also need to have count as an int, not string or StringBuilder.

```
public static void CreateText(string mas)
{
    if (mas.Length <= 80)
    {
        StringBuilder str;
        int count;
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++)
        {
            if (mas[i] >= '0' && mas[i] <= '9')
                count = count * 10 + mas[i] - '0';
            else
            {
                if (count == 0)
                    str.Append(mas[i]);
                else
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
                          str.Append(mas[i]);
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(str.ToString());
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
}
```

Comment: Could you add some text explaining what you changed and why it lowers the memory requirements?  It would make this a much better answer.

Comment: You might as well replace `int.TryParse(mas[i].ToString(), out n)` with `'0' <= text[i] && text[i] <= '9'` and `n = text[i] - '0'`. And skip `mas` altogether, index `text` instead.

Comment: Is the `mas` variable even needed? Can't strings be indexed directly in C#?

Comment: so , Error 1 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Append' and no extension method 'Append' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: The `count += (mas[i] - '0');` statement is no longer doing the same as before. Now this is adding the individual numbers up, rather than forming the int equivalanet of the string. Should be something like `count *= 10 + (mas[i] - '0');`

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't possible. Most of the RAM in a 36MB program is just core framework libraries. 36MB is **nothing**.

But I do see some potential improvements, the biggest of which are maintaining `count` as an **integer** rather than a string and using a string constructor and StringBuilder instead of appending to a string all the time:

```
public static void CreateText(string text)
{
    if (text != null && text.Length <= 80)
    {
        int n; int count = 0;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        char[] mas = text.ToCharArray();

        foreach(char c in text)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(c.ToString(), out n))
            {
                count = (count * 10) + n;
            }
            else
            {
                if (count == 0) 
                { 
                    result.Append(c);
                }
                else
                {
                    result.Append(new string(c, count));
                    count = 0;
                }
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
    }
}
```

There is a potential bug there if you want to be able to explicitly set 0 repetition in the input string. If that's the case, we'll need something that is slightly less efficient, but should still have a big improvement over the original:

```
public static void CreateText(string text)
{
    if (text != null && text.Length <= 80)
    {
        int n; int count = -1;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        char[] mas = text.ToCharArray();

        foreach(char c in text)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(c.ToString(), out n))
            {
                if (count == -1) count = 0;
                count = (count * 10) + n;
            }
            else
            {
                if (count == -1) 
                { 
                    result.Append(c);
                }
                else
                {
                    result.Append(new string(c, count));
                    count = -1;
                }
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: woooowww yes  work 100% ...Memory 15MB Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void CreateText(string text)
{
    if (text.Length <= 80)
    {
        var str = new StringBuilder();
        var count = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            int n;
            if (int.TryParse(text[i].ToString(), out n))
            {
                count.Append(text[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(count.ToString()))
                {
                    str.Append(text[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < Convert.ToInt32(count.ToString()); j++)
                    {
                        str.Append(text[i].ToString());
                    }
                    count.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
    }
}
```

What I did was:

- [Remove the string contetantions (since they are immutable) and used a StringBuilder instead.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306822)
- No need to convert to a `char[]` since your can treat a `String` as one (it implements the indexer)
- Moved the `n` closed to used to it's only allocated if needed

Comment: Can you give me an example of an input and output? and what errors are you getting?

Comment: input : 3A4B -----  output : AAABBBB

Comment: ERROR______An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Text.StringBuilder' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: Moving the `n` may be worse for many inputs, as it's now a separate variable in each loop... though I'd hope the compiler would optimize away the difference.

Comment: @TaGiAsadullazadeh I made some updates. On my machine it's sitting at [18.8MB](http://i.imgur.com/7Zpl350.png) (Release build that is).

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Any way to make sure that the compiler does the right thing?